# Debug Ruby on VsCode on MacOS with Rbenv

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubygems, rbenv

I know it's a question mentioned in multiple posts and yet I haven't been able to find the right answer. The error is:

> Debugger terminal error: Process failed: spawn rdebug-ide ENOENT

I have my Ruby being setup locally with Rbenv.

```
rbenv version
```

> 2.7.5

```
rbenv --version
```

> rbenv 1.2.0

I have installed locally both ruby-debug-ide and debase.

```
gem which debase
```

> /Users/MyName/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-0.2.4.1/lib/debase.rb

```
gem which ruby-debug-ide
```

> /Users/MyName/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb

if I use this command to see the env variables and set them up on launch.json as said in different answers on the web I see:

```
printf "\n\"env\": {\n  \"PATH\": \"$PATH\",\n  \"GEM_HOME\": \"$GEM_HOME\",\n  \"GEM_PATH\": \"$GEM_PATH\",\n  \"RUBY_VERSION\": \"$RUBY_VERSION\"\n}\n\n"


env": {
  "PATH": "/Users/MyName/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:/Users/MyName/.krew/bin:/Users/MyName/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
  "GEM_HOME": "",
  "GEM_PATH": "",
  "RUBY_VERSION": ""
}
```

and this happens I believe because I am using rbenv instead of rvm. So I have been trying to figure out myself what to put in GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH  What I have setup in launch.json is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Local Ruby File",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "{workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "{workspaceRoot}/my_main_test.rb",
            "env": {
                "PATH": "/Users/MyName/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin:/Users/MyName/.krew/bin:/Users/MyName/.rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin",
                "GEM_HOME": "/Users/MyName/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5",
                "GEM_PATH": "/Users/MyName/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0",
                "RUBY_VERSION": "2.7.5",
                "pathToRDebugIDE": "/Users/MyName.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.3/lib/"
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

And yet I haven't been able yet to run my code and hitting the breakpoint succesfully. Any possible idea?

Comment: Did you try launching VSCode from the terminal?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov yes, and made sure it was also a new terminal hence with the correct PATH variables in it